# React Hook, how to avoid multiple call of api?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use React hook and AntD table, the table has several pages to show the data from a backend server, now the problem is when users search on pages, the same api called two times, I know why this happened, but I don't know hot to avoid it.

1. This only happened when user search on other pages(not the first page)
2. **When user search on page, I want the table to show search result from the first page**.

the code as below, you can see the dependency of method `useEffect`:

1. the search condition
2. the `pageNum` and `pageSize`

When user input the search condition, and click `search` button, the api was fired(since `searchCondition` was changed). and then i update `pageNum` to `1`, the api fired again!(since `pageNum` was changed), how to make the api only called one time? thanks.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUsers(pageNum, pageSize, searchCondition)
}, [searchCondition, pageNum, pageSize])
```

and here is the handler for `search` button.

```
const listUser = (params: any) => {
    setSearchCondition(params)
    setPageNum(1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this, you may combine both of the actions into an action by using `useReducer`.

Replace `useState` by `useReducer`

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
  (state, action) => ({ ...state, ...action }),
  {
    searchCondition: initialState,
    pageNum: initialState
  }
);
```

Combine your action

```
const listUser = (params: any) => {
  dispatch({
    searchCondition: params,
    pageNum: 1
  });
}
```

Call API

```
useEffect(() => {
  getUsers(state.pageNum, pageSize, state.searchCondition)
}, [state.searchCondition, state.pageNum, pageSize])
```